# Python-Selenium-WebDriver The page is scrolling past elements without "clicking" on them even though the driver is supposed to

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, python-3.7

I am working on a project ,using Python & Selenium WebDriver in Firefox,in order to Open Google, search for a specific item and then have Selenium open first 5 search results in different tabs.

I want to do this by replicating the `Ctrl Button Down-->Click Link-->Ctrl Button Up` using selenium. The issue I faced while writing the"`Click` action was that the elements were out of ViewPort and these couldn't be clicked on. So I added the Move_to_Element action and the problem persisted (BUT IT DID OPEN THE FIRST 2 OR 3 LINKS). Then I added the `window.scroll_to` Script using the position of the element as reference but now it DOES NOT open ANY of the links. The browser opens up and it just scrolls to link after link till it reaches the last one.

Can u please help me figure out what I am doing wrong over here, as the logic seems fine and it worked before adding the `scroll_to` action ( at least for the first 2-3 links).

Many Thanks

```
#TO-DO open google
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.google.com")

#Selecting the search bar and send search text
searchElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.gLFyf')
searchElem.send_keys("cars")
searchElem.submit()
time.sleep(5)
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
# browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

found_elems=browser.find_elements_by_class_name('LC20lb')

#Selecting and clicking on first 5 pages
idx = 0

while idx <= min(len(found_elems),5):
    found_elem = found_elems[idx]

    #Find the height of the element
    ht = found_elem.location['y']

    print("Opening up ",found_elem.text)#Page Name
    try:
        print("In try block")

        #Scrolling to the element
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(ht))

        #Setting up Action Chains to move to elem-> Click on the links #with ctrl key down so as to open them in different tabs 
        ActionChains(browser)\
        .move_to_element(found_elem)\
        .key_down(Keys.CONTROL) \
        .click(found_elem) \
        .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
        .perform()
        print("Browser moved to "+str(ht))
        print("Exiting try")

    except Exception as e:
        print("In exception")
        print(e)
        break
    idx + = 1
```

Comment: Is that your whole script? Just want to confirm you’ve imported both Keys and ActionChains.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is it mandatory to use ctrl+click or just you want to open the link in new tab?

Comment: Hi, Yes I have imported both Keys and ActionChains. It is not mandatory to use ctrl+click , I just need to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to open the search links in new tabs. Then here is the simplified code.

```
browser.get("https://www.google.com")

#Selecting the search bar and send search text
searchElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.gLFyf')
searchElem.send_keys("cars")
searchElem.submit()
time.sleep(5)

found_elems=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='LC20lb']/parent::a")

#Selecting and clicking on first 5 pages
idx = 0

while idx <= min(len(found_elems),5):
    found_elem = found_elems[idx]
    # scroll to link
    found_elem.location_once_scrolled_into_view

    print("Opening up ",found_elem.text)#Page Name
    try:
        # opening the link in new tab
        browser.execute_script("window.open('"+found_elem.get_attribute('href')+"')")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
    idx =idx+1
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line in your loop,

```
idx + = 1
```

Has incorrect syntax. It should be `idx += 1` instead. So I don’t see how you’d get out of the loop, it would just keep iterating with `idx = 0`, am I missing something?

Comment: I think it's a typo. Would've thrown an error otherwise, since it's outside the try block

Comment: hi, yeah it was a typo actually. Had to format the code before uploading it and didn't do a very good job of it apparently xD.